# Couchbase backup and restore authentication error

Tags: memcached, couchbase, sasl

Using Couchbase v2.2. During the process of backup or restore mid-way the following error is seen after which the process of backup aborts.

```
s0 error: async operation: error: SASL auth exception
```

Has anyone else faced this issue or have any leads on why this happens?

Comment: Verified the source code of cbrestore and it is generated due to socket.error. Exact reasons not yet known. Could it be a connection timeout issue?